# Update data without sending back-end xhr request jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, websocket

I need to update notification if there's any change in database without slowing down the whole website, so I done this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myid">{{ $db_data }}</div>
```

**Back-end Request** (using Laravel):

```
$db_data = App\Marks::where(["subject_id" => 2])->pluck("marks")->first();
return view("myView", compact('db_data));
```

**jQuery request** every second:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#myid').load(location.href + " #myid");
    console.log("refreshed");
}, 1000);
```

The main problem here is it slows down the whole website, by sending requests in each second.

Someone recommended me to use Sockets but I'm not good at JavaScript, so I need a simple and versatile solution.

Comment: you can try with vue.js which can provide better result than jquery

Comment: Bro I mentioned that I'm not good at JavaScript, I'm a backend developer so is there any framework of JavaScript? In which I only have to include framework file and initialize a variable with db name and it will automatically update the HTML file with Dr change? Something like that I need.

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Is sending request every second really necessary? that sounds too costly.

Comment: @KapitanTeemo 5.7

Comment: @techie_28 I need to check that is there any change in database every second, so is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to learn [laravel broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#introduction). Though it will take a lot of time, but it would be worth it.

It is the most efficient way to make your application real-time. 
You can fire a query only if something changes in your database, not every second.